# How more exactly a GPU execute threads

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have a problem in understanding how GPU, more exactly which part from GPU execute a thread. 
I have understand how threads are grouped in blocks and grids.
Each GPU has one or more SM (streaming multiprocessor) and also more SP(stream processors or CUDA cores).

From what i have understand each SM receive a block of threads to be executed.
Here is a pic of how i see things.
[this is an example of how i see things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKdtx.png)
After that the grid is split into warps(32 threads).
Questions:

1. Why do we use grid if it is also split ? (if i have a grid with 200 threads this will be split into 32 threads and executed, so for what are good grids?)
2. Each SP execute a thread a time?
3. Each SM execute a single warp a time?

Comment: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mixing terminology. The hierarchy is grid -> block -> warp -> thread:

- A kernel is launched in a single grid. It maps to the whole GPU (unless you do some fancy multi-kernel computation, but that is more advanced)
- A grid consists of several blocks. Each block maps to a single SM, but a SM may handle multiple blocks if resources permit.
- A block is divided into warps. Depending on the GPU model, each SM handles 1 or 2 or 4 warps at a time. However, block is able to concurrently handle all the warps assigned to it. Switching between different warps happen very often and is doing so to hide memory and instruction latencies, dependencies, etc.
- A warp is split into 32 threads. All threads of a warp are executed at the very same moment by the SM, operating in SIMD.

Comment: Ok but for exemple my GPU ( GeForce GT 750M) has 2 SM and each SM has 192 cuda cores or SP. I don't find how many warp can execute my GPU but le's say 2. If a block with 192 threads come to SM1 it will execute only 2 warps a time (64 threads) and the rest of 128 SP (192 - 64) will do nophing ? And one more question..at the end each thread is executed by a SP, right?

Comment: The total number of warps execute at a time is #of cores / 32. Given your numbers it will be 192/32 = 6. However, realistically you want to launch even more as each SP is able to handle several threads concurrently. One way or another, every thread is going to be executed by a SP, concurrently or sequentially...

Comment: @CygnusX1 Just to confirm, is the total number of warps execute at a time actually larger than #of cores / 32? Besides SPs (i.e., cores here), there are other processing units like double precision units and LD/ST units etc. So there can be more warps executing at the same time?

Comment: @MarZzz The number of warps running at a time is related to the number of warp schedulers. This in turn is related to the number of cores, but as their number and their flavor increases with each generation of GPUs, it is better to look a the schedulers instead. Volta, for example, has FP32, FP64, INT32, Tensor & special function cores.